# In $\mathbb R^n$ with usual topology (euclidean metric), exists a bounded open set $A$ such that $A$ is different from the interior of its closure?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, examples-counterexamples

I expect that if $A$ is open set in $\mathbb R^n$ with the usual topology, then $A$ is contained in the interior of the closure of $A$.

But the converse is not necessarily true, I think that this is a hint for the pursued set.

---

The motivation of this claiming is because I want a bounded open set $A$ in which a bounded continuous real valued function defined all over $\mathbb R^n$ is Darboux integrable over the closure of a whilst it isn't over $A$ itself.

Again the motivation of the aforementioned motivation is that there is a theorem stating that if an integral of an function exists over a bounded set then it exists at the interior of this set and both are equal, so it seems rather absurd, but I think it is to show that $A$ is not the interior of closure of $A$.

---

Edit: Please if the answer may follows the motivation it would be of great help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider an open ball with the center removed.

Comment: it is a good example!

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ = $(0,1) \cup (1,2)$, then $A$ is open, bounded and we have $Cl(A) = [0,2]$ but $Int(Cl(A)) = Int([0,2])= (0,2) \neq A$.

Comment: your answer is right for what I requested, but stil that if a function is integrable over Cl(A)=[0,2] it also will be for A, for the boundary keep having 1-measure 0 :s

Comment: Consider an open set A whose boundary is a fat Cantor set, then Int(Cl) will be an open interval, A will have boundary with positive measure

Answer (score 1):

Re: Your first sentence: If $C\supset D$ then $Int(C)\supset Int (D).$ If $A$ is open then $A=Int(A).$ So if $A$ is open then  $Int(Cl(A))\supset Int (A)=A.$

A set which is the interior of its closure is called regular-open. And a set which is the closure of its interior is called regular-closed.